# Manually install DSE agents

Tags: datastax-enterprise, opscenter

I am attempting to get OpsCenter up and running and it is telling me that I need to the agents on my cluster. Which is fine.
the automatic install - for whatever reason - is not working so I am installing them manually by using the following command;

```
curl -L http://downloads.datastax.com/community/datastax-agent-<version-number>.tar.gz | tar xz
```

I tried 5.0.1 - to match the version of DSE and while it works - OpsCenter tells me it needs to be upgraded.

So I used 5.1.0 and that worked ,too - but also tells me it needs to be updated as well.

I am using DSE 5.0.1 and OpsCenter 6;
So I also tried using 6, 6.0 and 6.0.0 as versions - but apparently they don't exist.

Can someone please advise me what version am I supposed to be specifying in the curl command?

-Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would love to take the credit for it....
After chatting with DataStax, via email - i have JUST noticed that the documentation was updated yesterday, with respect to how to manually install the DSE agents.

The revised documentation now states to use the following command - which of course, now works correctly!

```
$ curl --user dsa_email_address:password -L http://downloads.datastax.com/enterprise/datastax-agent-version_number.tar.gz | tar xz
```